# MySQL select upto first occurrence of condition matching

Tags: mysql

```
Id      | Price
----------------
1       | 10
2       | 20
3       | 40
4       | 10
```

I need to select ids where first occurrence of summation of price is greater than or equal 55 matching from the bottom. At this case --
I will have 4,3,2 ids selected.

Comment: Most likely, that's not possible to achieve with a single query, and for sure not with a simple one.

Comment: I am trying, but can't find any solution :(. But pretty close.

Comment: According to your definition, you should fetch just 2 and 3 (sum=60)? I don't know in which order you want to start collecting ids. Boh. Think about it: `group by` can pick rows depending on their content (using `WHERE`), and you can filter already grouped data using `HAVING`, but that what you need is between them. You need to check what happens with some function applied to the whole group after adding new row and based on that decide if that should be included or not.

Comment: I have tried this query
    SELECT price_table.Id, price_table.Price, SUM(p.Price) p_price from price_table INNER JOIN price_table as p on price_table.Id <= p.Id GROUP BY price_table.Id HAVING p_price<=55

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this is kinda tricky for MySQL since it doesn't support any window fuctions and becuase you want to include the first occurrence as well. You can try this:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT t.id,
           (SELECT sum(s.price) FROM YourTable s
            WHERE s.id <= t.id) as cuml_sum
    FROM YourTable t) ss
WHERE ss.cuml_sum < 55
--Will select all the record will the sum < 55
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT t.id,
           (SELECT sum(s.price) FROM YourTable s
            WHERE s.id <= t.id) as cuml_sum
    FROM YourTable t) tt
WHERE tt.cuml_sum >= 55
ORDER BY tt.cuml_sum 
LIMIT 1
--Will select the first record that have sum >= 55
```

Comment: I just had to enclosed second query with first bracket. Other wise it was causing MySQL #1250 error